# The way to bind this for later invocation in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Just wondering how to handle "later invocation" when need to reference "this" in the outer scope. Aliase seems not good practice based on [idomatic.js](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js). And I quote:

> Beyond the generally well known use cases of  call  and  apply ,
>   always prefer  .bind( this )  or a functional equivalent, for creating
>   BoundFunction  definitions for later invocation. Only resort to
>   aliasing when no preferable option is available.

So is there any opinionated way in Ember? For example:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later(function() {
        resolve({ msg: 'Hold Your Horses' });
      }, 3000);
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    console.log(model.msg); // "Hold Your Horses"
  }
});
```

If, in the `Ember.run.later()` I want to do something after resolving with `this`:

```
this.controllerFor("application").set("dataReady", true);
```

for example.

I suppose, using aliase `that` would be:

```
  model() {
    let that = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later(function() {
        that.controllerFor('application').set('dataReady', true);
        resolve({ msg: 'Hold Your Horses' });
      }, 3000);
    });
  },
```

But what's the better way?

Comment: So, why not use bind(this)?

Comment: No why. Just wondering if Ember has its own way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using aliases you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain the scope. Something along these lines should work:

```
model() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve) => {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.controllerFor('application').set('dataReady', true);
      resolve({ msg: 'Hold Your Horses' });
    }, 3000);
  });
},
```

Notice that the callback that is passed to `Ember.run.later` doesn't need to be an arrow function because you can [pass an object as the first argument of `Ember.run.later`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later) to use as the context.

Comment: Does Ember provide browser support for arrow functions? The link said that Safari and IE is not supporting arrow functions.